# Want to make 3 divs of varying width inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create 3 divs inside another div.
The three divs are of varying width. First div contains a picture. I want to place the content of individual divs in its respective centers and also inside the container div.

HTML

```
 <div id="container">
        <div id="left">
            <img src="Pictures\38fafe4c2faaa7d207b0115720dedd21.jpg" alt="Pic Not available" 
            class="maskpic">
        </div>
        <div id="middle">
            <p class="firstmiddle">
                STAY HOME,
            </p>
            <p class="secondmiddle">
                STAY SAFE.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <p>
                Contactless Deliveries
                <br><br>
                All delivery staff trained in COVID-19<br>preventive measures
                <br><br>
                All Delivery and warehouse staff are equipped with<br>medical-grade hand Sanitizers
                <br><br>
                All warehouse staff undergo daily mandatory<br>thermal temperature scanning
                <br><br>
                No deliveries in 'highly affected' areas
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#left, #middle, #right { color: #333333; }
#left {
display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1; vertical-align: top;
}
.maskpic {
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
} 
#middle {
    display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1; vertical-align: top; font-size: 58px
} 
#right {
    display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1; vertical-align: top; font-size: 18px;
}
#left {
    width: 25%; background:#C0C0C0;
}
#middle {
    width: 50%; background: #C0C0C0;
}
#right {
    width: 25%; background:#C0C0C0;
}
```

Comment: Your `*display: inline;` (with the asterisk `*`) following the `display: inline-block` is throwing off my attempt to see what you are trying to do. The `width: 25%` on the `.maskpic` also confuses me, as it will make the image take up only one-fourth of it's div width — is that what you want? You may just want `auto` left- and right- margins, and/or text-align center(?) but I'm just not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick fix to that. Try using grid or flex to center all of the contents.

The container can use **FLEX** as it is easy to set-up;
"I think your intent is to make the div appear in one line using display: inline-block, the problem with that is that depending on the display it will not work as you intended. So I used flex-box as it will with the display size by itself on some extent."

The divs inside are made into **GRID** to satisfy the center alignment that you want.
"I used grid because it only needs one line to center everything: **place-items:center;** But do note that it must have only one direct child so that it will not make a new row. If you want to add many tags inside though, just make sure to put them under one parent."

example:

```
<div style="display:grid;place-items:center">
  <div> 
    ... items here ... 
  </div>
</div>
```

*For more info on flex and grid:*

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
#container {
width: 100%;
display:flex;
align-items:stretch;
}
#left, #middle, #right {
display:grid;
place-items:center;
color: #333333;
background: #C0C0C0;
width: 25%;
font-size: 14px;
padding:1rem;
}
.maskpic {
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
}
#middle {
    width: 50%; 
    font-size: 48px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <div id="left">
            <img src="Pictures\38fafe4c2faaa7d207b0115720dedd21.jpg" alt="Pic Not available" 
            class="maskpic">
        </div>
        <div id="middle">
            <p>
                STAY HOME, <br>STAY SAFE.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <p>
                Contactless Deliveries
                <br><br>
                All delivery staff trained in COVID-19<br>preventive measures
                <br><br>
                All Delivery and warehouse staff are equipped with<br>medical-grade hand Sanitizers
                <br><br>
                All warehouse staff undergo daily mandatory<br>thermal temperature scanning
                <br><br>
                No deliveries in 'highly affected' areas
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```